# How to filter contacts from Inbuilt Android Contact Application?

Tags: android

I have a button on my activity, onClick of which I am calling Inbuilt Contacts Application using "startActivityForResult". When user selects a Contact from the screen, I am retreiving the data on "OnActivityResult" and storing them in my database.

Now when the User Clicks the button again, I do not want to show them the Selected Contact again. So I need to put some where condition in my **Intent** which is passed in "startActivityForResult". How do I do that?

Below is my code

```
public void onClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

Also, I want to display only Users having Mobile Numbers on the Contacts Screen.
Few Search on this, gave me something called "**Phone.Type_Mobile**" but how to pass it to my Intent?

I know that the above 2 can be acheived after I get the data in my "OnActivityResult", but I need this filtering to happen when the screen is displayed to user i.e before "OnActivityResult" is called.

Comment: I suggest you populate a separate listview after querying contacts and use this listview for further use where you will have control over which contacts to display. Contacts addition can be done by alter query..

Comment: You can't arbitrarily add that sort of information to the intent. If you want to apply your own selection criteria, you need to build your own contact selection screen that queries that Contacts Provider. http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html